# Usar eval en strings con tipos en string

Tags: python

¿Hay alguna forma de usar `eval` o otra función para hacer que un tipo en string se pueda convertir en un tipo? Por ejemplo:

`>>> eval('(<class \'str\'>,)')`

`(<class 'str'>,)`

Esto en realidad provoca `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Quieres decir, ¿Se puede generar un objeto del tipo dado por un string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta donde sé, no hay ninguna función que dada esa string en particular te devuelva el tipo señalado en la string. Quizás por el hecho de que esto es un caso de uso muy extraño.

Sin embargo, se pudiera conseguir lo que deseas, utilizando ciertos módulos y sus funciones proveídos por defecto por Python.

En concreto, se podría usar `re.findall()` para obtener los nombres de los módulos y de las clases que se encuentren representados dentro de la string. A partir de esos nombres, con `sys.modules` pudieses obtener el módulo como tal que deseas, y luego con `getattr()` pudieses obtener el objeto `type`.

Debo decir que no sé si recomendaría realmente hacer algo así, pero de cualquier manera aquí está un código que hace lo que pareces querer conseguir.

*Como veo que la string que muestras en el ejemplo representa una tupla, haré un ejemplo que contenga distintas clases dentro de esa tupla*

```
import re
import sys

from some_module import SomeClass


# Esta clase es solo un ejemplo para incluir otro elemento más en la tupla de la string
class ExampleClass:
    pass

# Esta sería la string que quieres convertir en una lista que contenga los types como tal
string = "(<class 'str'>, <class '__main__.ExampleClass'>, <class 'some_module.SomeClass'>)"

# Una expresión regular para extraer el nombre del módulo y de la clase de cada elemento
# de la string anterior, y guardarlo en una variable 
module_and_class_names = re.findall("<class \'(?:(\w+)\.)?(\w+)\'>", string)
# Esta lista contendrá los types reales
types = []
for module_name, class_name in module_and_class_names:
    # Obtener el módulo donde se encuentra el type
    module = sys.modules.get(module_name, __builtins__)
    # Obtener el objeto type como tal y appendearlo en la lista "types"
    types.append(getattr(module, class_name))

print(types)
```

**Output**

```
[<class 'str'>, <class '__main__.ExampleClass'>, <class 'some_module.SomeClass'>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente `eval()` toma el string que se usa como parámetro, y lo intenta interpretar como comida para el interprete. Si quieres obtener una representación del tipo `<class 'clase'>`, solo basta con pasarle el nombre de la clase rodeado por comillas.

```
print(eval("str"))
```

Esto funciona con cualquier clase, ya que todas las clases tienen el mismo tipo de representación. Por ejemplo, si creas una clase y lo pasas el nombre encerrado por comllas a `eval()` el interprete va devolver como si se hiciera el print a la clase (sin las comlillas).

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

print(eval("Clase"))
```

Estos ejemplos son lo mismo que hacer `print(clase)`, `eval()` va a ser lo posible por evaluar la cadena como código de Python. Según la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

> The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a **Python expression.**

Solo te basta con pasar el nombre de la clase y/o tipo en un string por `eval()` para obtener lo que buscas.